# Get all user data from hybridauth

Tags: hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

I need to get all user available data like work experience and education does hybridauth provide that ?

Now I can get user basic data using hybridauth. I want to get all user data from Google+ ,Facebook and linked in. Any help ?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far to get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information that you can retrieve from social networks depend on what the providers offer.

Currently neither of those providers has functionality to go beyond getting the basic user information from the social network and maybe posting to user feed there.
It's also unlikely that this will be added as very few need it. It requires additional permissions and for other reasons.

But you can just add additional functionality to the given provider in `hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/`

Comment: Thanks, I added other function to to Provider for each of Facebook, Lin and G+. So now I can retrieve their education and workExperience data.